# nc -lvnp (port) Non-responsive w/ PHP Reverse Shell til closed

Tags: php, netcat, nc

I am currently working on Machine's on HackTheBox. I've used nc -lvnp (port) quite a bit and i've never ran into this issue:

```
$nc -lvnp 4444
listening on [any] 4444 ....
connect to [my IP] from (unknown) [IP of Machine] (port)
/bin/sh: 0: can't access tty; job control turned off
$ whoami

(no response... im able to write in this space, but there is no $... EX:
cd /
python3 *insert stuff here*)
```

looks normal to start it, right? well, it NEVER prints anything from whoami... if i ^C it, it will print out the right response either on the Browser if i use my reverse shell there, *OR* it will show up in my other terminal:

```
$curl -H "Cookie: PHPSESSID=id stuff" "link to site"

(it pauses on an empty space right here til i quit the netcat)
$(proper response to $whoami)
```

keep in mind, this ONLY shows up when i stop or control + C the netcat... So it doesnt do a single response until its closed. i tried stacking commands but it just doesnt work. it can only hold 1 cmd til i quit it then after i quit it shows me the response.

I've never seen this before and im very confused. I've tried doing different ways of doing this, and nothing is working.

Edit 1: fix on code |
Edit 2: Here is the [EXACT Terminal windows (imgur link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjOPM.jpg) / what I see. | Edit 3: fixed title